# Angular CLI building SourceMaps, but not deploying them

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v8

We are using a front-end error logging tool `Sentry` to see the errors we get in our angular applications.

`Sentry` allows users to upload their SourceMap files, so I went into our `angular.json` and set `"sourceMap": true`. As expected, it creates a lot of `.js.map` files that we upload to `Sentry`, but we get rid of them and **do not** deploy them, for the obvious security reasons.

The problem is that for some reason, Google Chrome Dev Tools somehow know that SourceMap files were generated and even tries to access them!

[image]

So here is my question:

- How does Google Chrome work out that SourceMapswere generated? I assume something in the `html`, `css` or `js` files tells this.
- How do I work around that? I want to get the SourceMaps, but I don't want anyone to know that they exist and especially their locations.

**Side note:** Although I mention Sentry multiple times, it has nothing to do with the question. I just wanted to explain, why we want this.

Comment: `//# sourceMappingURL=`. The location is guessable anyway, if they aren't actually deployed why does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First:**
As @jonrsharpe noted, it turns out that Angular injects `//# sourceMappingURL=...` comments at the end of `css` and `js` files and Google Chrome (possibly other browsers as well) parses it and uses it for to display original stack traces.

**Second:**
It seems that this is doable, by configuring `hidden: true` for the `sourceMap` parameter, like this:

```
"sourceMap": { "scripts": true, "styles": true, "hidden": true, "vendor": true }
```

It seems that `sourceMap` can be either a `bool` or a complex object. Please look at the [angular docs here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-and-source-map-configuration).